# Finding centroid of two(or more) contours

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv3.0, centroid

I have `binary images` like below. I want to get cetroid of white regions.(not centroids of each contours) This image has two seperated contours

[image: binary image]]

```
    _, contour, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    total_contour = contour[0]
    for ctr in contour[1:]:
            total_contour = np.concatenate((total_contour, ctr), axis =0)

    mmt = cv2.moments(total_contour)
    self.cy = int(mmt['m10']/mmt['m00']) 
    self.cx = int(mmt['m01']/mmt['m00'])
```

So I just simply added `np.array` of `contours`, and used `moments` in `openCV`.
It looks working well... but I'm not sure that `self.cx` and `self.cy` are really cetroid of white regoins.

Am I doing right? If not, what would be better method?

Comment: Your code is fine, but it might be a bit too complicated if all you want is the centroid of the white region. Check out the one-liner for finding the centroid in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unsure about the result you're getting from `openCV`, you can always just calculate the centroid yourself. It's quite simple, here's how:

```
centroid = [nz.mean() for nz in binary_image.nonzero()]
```

If you want the centroid in the same x,y index format as you're getting from openCV, do this:

```
import numpy as np
centroid = np.array([nz.mean() for nz in binary_image.nonzero()][2::-1], dtype=int)
```

I ran the above line of code on the image you posted in your question, and here's what I got:

```
[133  44]
```

If it makes you feel better, that does match the values that I get for `cx` and `cy` when I run the openCV snippet you posted. So I guess you were doing it right all along!